# Observable value not updated on UI

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs-observables

I'm working on an Angular app and among other features, now I'm working on an image gallery (carousel).

When the user opens the image gallery, he's also able to upload new photos.

Because I need to know the upload process globally, I'm trying to implement a service for this as follow:

In **ts** component I have the following function:

```
onUploadFile(files: File[]) {
    if (!files?.length) {
      return;
    }

    const uploading = this.attachmentsService
      .uploadMultiple(files)
      .map((x) => ({ attachment: x }));

    uploading.forEach((file) => {
      this.filesStateService
        .getProgress(file.attachment.url)
        .pipe(untilDestroyed(this))
        .subscribe({
          complete: () => {
            this.referenceAttachments = [...this.referenceAttachments];
          },
          error: () => {
            this.deleteAttachment(file);
          },
        });
    });

    this.referenceAttachments = [...uploading, ...this.referenceAttachments];
}
```

**attachments.service.ts**:

```
uploadMultiple(files: File[]) {
    if (!files?.length) {
      return [];
    }

    return files.map((x) => this.upload(x));
}

upload(file: File) {
    const fileUpload = this.filesService.upload(file);

    this.filesStateService.addProgress(fileUpload.url, fileUpload.progress$);

    const attachment: Attachment = {
      url: fileUpload.url,
      size: file.size,
      type: file.type,
    };

    return attachment;
}
```

**files.service.ts**:

```
upload(file: File) {
    ...
    return {
      url: fileUrl,
      progress$: new Observable<number>((observer) => {
        blockBlobClient
          .uploadData(file, {
            onProgress: this.onProgress(observer),
          })
          .then(
            this.onUploadComplete(observer, file, fileUrl),
            this.onUploadError(observer, fileUrl)
          );
      }).pipe(distinctUntilChanged(), startWith(0), shareReplay()),
    };
}

private onUploadError(observer: Subscriber<number>, fileUrl: string) {
    return (error: any) => {
      observer.error(error);

      this.filesStateService.removeProgress(fileUrl);
    };
}

private onUploadComplete(
    observer: Subscriber<number>,
    file: File,
    fileUrl: string
) {
    return () => {
      observer.next(file.size);

      this.filesStateService.removeProgress(fileUrl);

      observer.complete();
    };
}

private onProgress(observer: Subscriber<number>) {
    return (progress: TransferProgressEvent) =>
      observer.next(progress.loadedBytes);
}
```

In the view, the progress is rendered as follow:

```
<app-file-upload-progress
     *ngIf="file.attachment.url | fileProgress | async as progress"
     [progress]="progress"
     [size]="file.attachment?.size"
></app-file-upload-progress>
```

**file-progress.pipe** is just returning the progress form the list:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'fileProgress',
})
export class FileProgressPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private filesStateService: FilesStateService) {}

  transform(value: string): Observable<number> {
    if (!value) {
      return null;
    }

    return this.filesStateService.getProgress(value);
  }
}
```

and the **files-state.service** where the files progress are stored:

```
@Injectable()
export class FilesStateService {
  filesProgress: Map<string, Observable<number>> = new Map();

  addProgress(url: string, progress$: Observable<number>): void {
    this.filesProgress.set(url, progress$);
  }

  removeProgress(url: string): void {
    this.filesProgress.delete(url);
  }

  getProgress(url: string): Observable<number> {
    return this.filesProgress.get(url);
  }
}
```

I can't understand why, after the file was successfully uploaded and the progress is removed from the `filesProgress` list, the **app-file-upload-progress** is not removed from the interface.

I also tried to use `pure: false` in **file-progress.pipe** and with this, after the upload is complete if I click on another element, the changes are reflected and the progress is removed from UI (but from what I've read, using `pure: false` will lead to poor performance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `ChangeDetectorRef` **service**.

ChangeDetector is necessary when some areas of the code, angular, cannot detect changes using default detection.
The good news is that to use ChangeDetector in your code, it is one line of code. All you have to do is after the changes `this.detector.detectChanges();`
This will also require that you previously declared the service in the constructor.

```
constructor(private detector: ChangeDetectorRef)
```

Demo:

```
 constructor(private detector: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

someMethod(){
 setInterval(() => {

          this.detector.detectChanges();

        }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Using `ChangeDetectorRef` in **files-state.service** I'm getting `NullInjectorError`.

Comment: You do not call it in the service but after the service method invocation is done in your *component*

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by emitting on success besides the file size, a null value.

```
private onUploadComplete(observer: Subscriber<number>, file: File) {
    return () => {
      observer.next(file.size);
      observer.next(null);
      observer.complete();

      this.filesStateService.removeProgress(fileUrl);
    };
}
```